# Out of memory error when reading Realm database after restarting the app

Tags: android, realm

I am currently using Realm database on my Android application to retrieve data according to user defined filters and to synchronize with a remote database. After making several requests the app works pretty fine (it consumes about 30 MB of memory, what is ok, taking into account I am using other components and services like maps, etc.). However, when closing the app (swipe on recent apps list) and restarting it, after two or three queries the memory consumption starts increasing considerably (above 100 MB), so it takes too long to make a query and finally the app crashes because of an `OutOfMemoryError`. Tracking the application instances on Android Studio I see a lot of instances of `io.realm.internal.NativeObjectReference`.

According to realm documentation I have tried two things, without success:

1. Getting a Realm instance with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in a class constructor, which is responsible to query the Realm database, and closing the database with `mRealm.close()`from `onDestroy` method on main activity.
2. Getting a Realm instance with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` right before starting a database operation, and closing it right after the operation ends. With asynchronous operations I make something like this

   ```
   mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
   mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
       @Override
       public void execute(Realm realm) {
          //perform transaction
       }
   }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {

       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {
           mRealm.close();
           //notify calling function
       }
   }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
       @Override
       public void onError(Throwable error) {
           mRealm.close();
       }
   });
   ```

   with non-asynchronous operations I make something like this

   ```
   mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
   RealmResults<DealLocal> dealLocals = mRealm.where(DealLocal.class).findAll();
   mRealm.close();
   ```

I use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in two classes: one to synchronize with the remote database, and the other one to make the user defined queries. However, at this moment all the calls are made from the main activity, and I guarantee only one operation on the database is made at the same time (i.e. I synchronize first and then make the user defined queries). When a query takes too long because of an excessive memory usage and I kill the app (swipe on recent apps list), the memory usage does not go back to normal.

How would be the correct way to handle the realm instances and operations on my application in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: A `NativeObjectReference` will be created for each Realm object you are accessing, so if you see a lot of them, most likely you are either keeping a reference to _a lot_ of objects or you are iterating a list. Note that they are extremely lightweight, so even though there might be many of them, they should normally not cause problems. Especially since they would be garbage collected if you no longer reference the Realm object.

Comment: Yes, I am actually iterating over a list and making insertions. It works fine before I kill and restart the app, then it gets slow and crashes. I close the realm database on the `executeTransactionAsync` callbacks

Comment: Without an example project that demonstrates this. I think it will be hard to tell what is going on

Comment: How many objects are you iterating on?